# Clear all asp:TreeView checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, treeview

What is the best way to clear all of a `asp:TreeView` checkboxes so that they are all unchecked?  I've tried iterating through the treenodes and unchecking but this isn't working especially for child node checkboxes.

Comment: Can you use Javascript, there is something on here: http://pushpontech.wordpress.com/2007/06/06/aspnet-20-treeview-checkbox-checkuncheck-all-script/

Comment: Do you know what recursion is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own answer is close, but won't traverse down the tree. Try a recursive method like this.

```
   Private Sub unCheckNodesIncludingDescendants(Node as TreeNode)
        Node.checked=false
        For Each tn As TreeNode In Node.ChildNodes
            tn.Checked = False
            unCheckNodesIncludingDescendants(tn)
        Next tn
    End Sub
```

Your initial call would look like this:

```
private sub UncheckWholeTree(TreeControl as TreeView)
    For each rootNode as TreeNode in TreeControl.nodes
      unCheckNodesIncludingDescendants(rootNode)
    Next rootNode
end sub
```